Two PGP keys one email generating a different public key
I am looking for an explanation for a scenario that I encountered.
I created two sample key pairs with same name and email using gpg(GnuPG).
pub   ed25519 2024-12-14 [SC]
      EE1D0421E762941939DAD2ED5BA3B96F99C01CFC
uid           [ultimate] RIZER <ri@ri.com>
sub   cv25519 2024-12-14 [E]

pub   ed25519 2024-12-14 [SC]
      66B887039701E1A7240DA351978108403A6EAC64
uid           [ultimate] RIZER <ri@ri.com>
sub   cv25519 2024-12-14 [E]


Now if I try to export the public key of each of them, I will get this output.
$ gpg --export --armor EE1D0421E762941939DAD2ED5BA3B96F99C01CFC
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=CDXc
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

$ gpg --export --armor 66B887039701E1A7240DA351978108403A6EAC64
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=iryh
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

Now If I try to export using email as argument, I get something completely different from the two above.
$ gpg --export --armor ri@ri.com
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=y6+c
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

I noticed that the characters in the first 8 lines are similar to first key.
Same result is produced when I use the name as argument.
Questions

Is the third key a mix of first two?
Can I encrypt using the third key?
If the third key can encrypt a file, Can we decrypt the file using private key of the any of the first two keys?


You're exporting a subkey of one of those keys. Use gpg to inspect the exported key and it will tell you which one.
